# StackExchange.com site text is wrapping to next line

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stackexchange.com

[image: Improper Wrapping]

Fairly obvious, answers should be next to the `10.1 million`. It didn't matter how big or small I made the window or resolution.

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome on Windows. Zooming out to 90% fixes it for me, but that's neither here nor there really.

Comment: Sorry should of included, I'm using Chrome on Linux Mint-13

Comment: Woo, 10 million answers!

Comment: @DavidFullerton yay 10 million answers, now fix it! :-)

Comment: @DavidFullerton haha, you guys already fixed it. good job